# date formatting using lubridate package in R

Tags: r, lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
options(lubridate.verbose = TRUE)
dmy("03-Dec-2011", "03-12-2010", "312-2010", "02022011")

[1] "2011-12-03" "2010-12-03" NA           "2011-02-02"
```

```
1 parsed with %d-%b-%Y
1 parsed with %d-%Om-%Y
1 parsed with %d%Om%Y
0 parsed with %d-%m-%Y
0 parsed with %d%m%Y
```

Does anyone know why `dmy` is trying both `%d-%b-%Y` and `%d-%Om-%Y` for the first two entries when it can be simply done with `%d-%Om-%Y`?

Also, why it is checking `%d-%m-%Y` when it already has `%d-%Om-%Y`?

Comment: `%b` is month name in your locale (like Jan, Feb, Dec) which I don't think can be identified with `%m`. Though I don't know what `%Om` is, all the dates seem to match with `%m`.

Comment: In the help page of `parse_date_time` it defines "%Om: Matches numeric month and English alphabetic months (Both, long and abbreviated forms)". If so, the first two dates can be matched by `%d-%Om-%Y`. Not sure why it has been fallen into two groups.